# Как вызвать Activity, написанную на Kotlin, из Activity, написанную на Java, используя метод newIntent?

Tags: java, android, activity, kotlin, runtime

У меня есть `Activity1.java` и `Activity2.kt`.

В `Activity2.kt` есть вспомогательный объект (компаньон) `newIntent`:

```
companion object {
   @JvmStatic
   fun newIntent(parent: Activity, extra: Int): Intent {
      val intent = Intent(parent, Activity2.javaClass) //кстати есть ли разница между *.javaClass и *::class.java ?
      intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CONST, extra)
      return intent
   }
}
```

Задача – из `Activity1.java` вызвать `Activity1.kt` методом `startActivity`.
Сейчас это выглядит вот так:

```
startActivity(Activity2.newIntent(this, extra));
```

Выглядит отлично, и IDE не ругается, но в рантайме получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {path.path/path.path.Activity2$Companion}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

То есть идёт попытка обратиться к классу `Activity2.Companion`.

Я знаю что это будет работать если обе активности будут написаны на Kotlin и в курсе про всякие удобные способы вызова активностей непосредственно в Kotlin, но меня интересует именно эта ситуация – вызвать активность на котлине из активности на джаве.

Проблема возникла в ходе переписывания существующего Java-кода на Kotlin. Можно конечно переписать сразу весь код, но я решил делать поэтапно – файл за файлом, так как проект большой. К тому же котлин совместим с джавой, так почему бы и нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если надо запустить, то можно сделать так

```
   companion object {
    fun start(context: Context) {
        val intent = Intent(context, Activity2::class.java)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Comment: Такой способ тоже уже пробовал, но ошибка не меняется – всё ещё обращается к `Activity2.Companion`, а это не является активностью.

Comment: По любому же кто-то уже переписывал свои проекты на Kotlin, и не за один раз целиком, а заменяя один файл за другим. Собственно я вот заменил `Activity2.java` на `Activity2.kt` и хочу протестировать результат, но появляется эта ошибка. Из этого делаю вывод что я не правильно реализую то что хочу. В Kotlin нет статических полей/методов, и Factory-методы делаются через компаньонов, но видимо чего-то я не понимаю.

Comment: Тогда надо проверить наличие этой активити в манифесте. Надо проверить с названием пакета. Проблема тут не kotlin.

Comment: Кстати если убрать @JvmStatic то получится ровно такая же ошибка, просто нужно будет вручную прописывать `Activity2.Companion.newIntent()`

Comment: Активность в манифесте присутствует, это уже тоже проверено. Я прошу вас обратить внимание на текст ошибки: там сказано что не найдена активность Activity2$Companion. Но такой активности в принципе существовать не должно, так как это всего лишь объект-компаньон, имитирующий статический метод.

Comment: Пожалуйста попробуйте мой код. Заменив свой. Он не возвращает интент, а сразу запускает активити. У Вас ошибка, что идет поиск Activity2$Companion, которой нет.

Comment: Попробовал, получил другую, менее понятную ошибку:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment MyFragment{887ee99 id=0x7f090099 android:switcher:2131296409:0}: was android:switcher:2131296409:0 now android:switcher:2131296409:1`, где MyFragment это Activity1.java, я просто утрировал для простоты.

Comment: Тогда activitys - это fragments?
Если нет, то надо использовать контекст. Если есть проблемы с запуском, то лучше попробовать запусть новую пустую activity. Возможно новая проблемв уже в запускаемой activity

Comment: Окей, видимо дело все таки в запускаемой активности. Спасибо за дискуссию.